# how to close the menu when clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript

I have a code, but I need help please, how can I close the menu when clicking on a link item. that's what I'm stuck on

```
$('.burger').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.menu__list').slideToggle();
});

let ul = document.querySelector('.menu__list');
let li = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link');

li.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ul.querySelector('.menu__link--active').classList.
    remove('menu__link--active');

    el.classList.add('menu__link--active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add .slideToggle() to the click listener:

```
$('.burger').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.menu__list').slideToggle();
});

let ul = document.querySelector('.menu__list');
let li = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link');

li.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ul.querySelector('.menu__link--active').classList.
    remove('menu__link--active');

    el.classList.add('menu__link--active');
    $('.menu__list').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, only I added a check for the active class of the burger button

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 solutions, first, make a transparent div with the height and width of the screen and make and a click event listener on it to close the menu, the other option is to use focus and blur event listener

Answer (score 0):

Believing that you are having a list of items in your example I am providing the below solution.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
   $(".closemenu").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<style> 
#panel, #flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
.closemenu{
   
   font-weight:bold;
   list-style:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">
<ul>
<li class="closemenu">item1</li>
<li class="closemenu">item2</li>
<li class="closemenu">item3</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```